# Can connectSlotsByName connect to selection model changes?

Tags: qt, signals-slots

In my main window (`QMainWindow`) I have a `QTableView` (named `commandsTableView`). Now I want to react on its selection changes.

I made a slot and connected it manually to `ui.commandsTableView->selectionModel()`. All works fine.

But then I thought: why not use auto-connection (especially that there will be more connections to be done)? At least it will add more force to consistent naming rules.

Yet I wasn't able to find proper name syntax. I tried:

- `on_commandsTableView_selectionModel_selectionChanged`,
- `on_commandsTableViewSelectionModel_selectionChanged`,
- `on_commandsTableView_selectionChanged`,
- `on_commandsTableView___selectionChanged`

but neither worked. In all cases there is there is a message on output when running the app (with corresponding slot name, here only first given as an example):

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_commandsTableView_selectionModel_selectionChanged(QItemSelection,QItemSelection)
```

*(Why there are no assertions in response for connection errors - that I cannot understand. I lost much time wondering what is wrong before I spotted those - and alike - messages on output.)*

The object returned by `ui.commandsTableView->selectionModel()` has an empty name. But setting it to `selectionModel` prior to making a call to `connectSlotsByName` doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **[the documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName)** `connectSlotsByName()` only supports signatures like

`void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>);`

According to **[the sources](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/blobs/8e7b86de2c69c9c48c8431bf6ea9e6b0b29f00f8/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp#line3219)** that's the only form it checks (watch how it collects a list of children, then matches parent's method names against names of the children).

Hence, to be able to use auto-connection you would have needed a named selection model, which would continue existing from the call to `connectSlotsByName()` onwards. Each time you change the selection model (not likely) or the model (likely) you'd have to name the selection model and auto-connect again. But alas `connectSlotsByName()` will duplicate all other connections as it doesn't seem to check if connections are unique, so we have to connect signals to such dynamic children as models, scenes *etc* manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's

```
on_selectionModel_selectionChanged(const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected)
```

Comment: artm's answer made me realize what you truly (seemed) to mean. Not only I have to change the function name *but also* call `setObjectName` on the selection model with `"selectionModel"` name (in the above case). I down-voted you but now I want to take it back. Yet I cannot (vote already locked) unless you will edit your answer. If it do then I will remove my down-vote. But be more explicit next time!

Comment: That's OK. I will just down vote you back. Just kidding. :) Don't worry about the vote. It's not real anyway. BTW. I don't know how much more specific can it be. I even spelt out the whole function signature. :)

Comment: Well, the crucial thing I missed was the call to `setObjectName`. I did mention that in the question but treated it only as an episode. Since it didn't work with any of my functions I removed that call and then when testing your function it didn't work. ;)